# Which input format is the best for sound recognition in recurrent neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create sound or pitch recognition with recurrent deep neural network. And I'm wondering with what input will I get best results.

Should I feed DNN with amplitudes or with FFT(Fast Fourier transform) result?

Is there any other format that is known to produce good results and fast learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While MFCCs have indeed been used in music information retrieval research (for genre classification etc...), in this case (pitch detection) you may want to use  a semi-tone filterbank or constant Q transform as a first information reduction step. These transformations match better with musical pitch.

But I think it's also worth trying to use the audio samples directly with RNNs, in case you have a huge number of samples. In theory, the RNNs should be able to learn the wave patterns corresponding to particular pitches.

From your description, it's not entirely clear what type of "pitch recognition" you're aiming for: monophonic instruments (constant timbre, and only 1 pitch sounding at a time)? polyphonic (constant timbre, but multiple pitches may be sounding simultaneously)? multiple instruments playing together (multiple timbres, multiple pitches)? or even a full mix with both tonal and percussive sounds? The hardness of these use cases roughly increases in the order I mentioned them, so you may want to start with monophonic pitch recognition first.

To obtain the necessary amount of training examples, you could use a physical model or a multi-sampled virtual instrument to generate the audio samples for particular pitches in a controlled way. This way, you can quickly create your training material instead of recording it and labeling it manually. But I would advise you to at least add some background noise (random noise, or very low-level sounds from different recordings) to the created audio samples, or your data may be too artificial and lead to a model that doesn't work well once you want to use it in practice.

Here is a paper that might give you some ideas on the subject:
An End-to-End Neural Network for Polyphonic Piano Music Transcription
(Siddharth Sigtia, Emmanouil Benetos, and Simon Dixon)
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.01774.pdf

Comment: Thank you sooo much for you guidance! Much apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The [Mel-frequency cepstrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) is general used for speech recognition.
[mozilla DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech) is using MFCCs as input to their DNN.

For python implementation you can use [python-speech-features](http://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lib.